# htaccess not working cant find file

Tags: php, apache, file, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  


RewriteRule ^Download/(.*)/?$ ./downloadit.php?key=$1 
RewriteRule ^Buy/(.*)/?$ ./buy.php?key=$1
RewriteRule ^Admin/(.*)/?$ ./admin.php?cmd=$1&key=$2
RewriteRule ^Admin/Edit/(.*)/?$ ./editfile.php?key=$1
```

I dont normally work with Apaches Rewrite Engine so Im not sure.

The Link I am Attempting to Parse is: http://Website.com/~User/Download/Testlicious/

I have 4 Files in total, all of them php files. I will like to rewrite directly to those files

But it keeps giving me a 404 cannot find /downloadit.php its in the same directory, same with the rest.

*UPDATE*****
Since on on a Virtual Host, Duh. I need to Set my Rewrite Base Correctly, DOH

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~GameCenter/
RewriteRule ^Download/(.*)/?$ ./downloadit.php?key=$1 [qsa]
RewriteRule ^Buy/(.*)/?$ /buy.php?key=$1
RewriteRule ^Admin/(.*)/?$ /admin.php?cmd=$1&key=$2
RewriteRule ^Admin/Edit/(.*)/?$ /editfile.php?key=$1
```

Now everything now Links and Works but the Problem now is that $0/$1/$2 dont trigger anything in the Files. Nothing Spits out in $_POST['key']

Now I guess Step 1 of the Problem is Solved. But now onto O_O STEP 2!!

Comment: is this a linux environment?

Comment: also, try without the RewriteCond bits -- try:RewriteRule    ^Download/(.*)/?$    /downloadit.php?key=$1    [NC,L]

Comment: Tried that as well, still no good. It will see Download/ but it wont find the downloadit.php file and their in the same directory :|

Comment: @BioblazePayne what's your directory structure like? Is your `htaccess` file in the same directory as `Download`, `Buy` and `Admin`? And are those 4 PHP files in the same directory as the `htaccess` file?

Comment: @BioblazePayne and are all those files/directories in the root folder of the website or in a subfolder?

Comment: All of them are in the same Directory the ./ root directory the public_html directory Xd thats why im annoyed.

Comment: Try $_GET['key'] or $_REQUEST['key'] instead of $_POST['key'].

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the conditions in for each rule, <strike>and I'm pretty sure the `RewriteRule` pattern match requires a slash at the start too</strike>.

I've assumed the 4 PHP files are in the same directory that your `.htaccess` file is in.

The `[L]` tells `mod_rewrite` to stop parsing the `.htaccess` file for the current request:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^Download/(.*)/?$ /downloadit.php?key=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^Buy/(.*)/?$ /buy.php?key=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  
# You've only specified one matching group here, so $2 will be blank
RewriteRule ^Admin/(.*)/?$ /admin.php?cmd=$1&key=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^Admin/Edit/(.*)/?$ /editfile.php?key=$1 [L]
```

Comment: No, in a per-directory context, the request URI _never_ starts with a slash.

Comment: Now Ive tried what you typed and it still doesnt work.
Not Found

The requested URL /downloadit.php was not found on this server.
Very annoying XD lolz.